# jQuery masonry preload images from string

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-masonry

I'm using masonry and a sort of version of infinite scroll that doesn't actually use the library. The initial images go into layout correctly but the added images don't.. they just add in a row.

I believe this because they are loaded from a string they don't have height/width properties to select the position.  I think so because when I wrap them in a div of a predetermined size they correctly go into the layout (but the images will be all different heights)

I have a set number of images on pageload that correctly apply masonry to their layout.

Then using PHP calls to sql, I gather an array of image paths, which I turn into a javascript array:

```
var images = [
<?php
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo "'/$image',\n";
} ?>
];
$(images).each(function() {
var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
});
</script>
```

Then I load them in 5 at a time on the trigger event using the append for masonry:

```
$appendage +=  '<div class="box append"><img src="' + images[i] + '" /></div>';
count++;
    }   

var $container = $('#result');      
$container.append( $appendage ).masonry( 'appended', $appendage );
```

I have tried all sorts of schemes for preloading images to no avail..

```
    $(images).each(function() {
     (new Image).src = this;
    });
```

can anyone suggest a method, perhaps a better approach altogether to go from a database of image paths as a starting point to images that load into masonry as appends when you scroll to the bottom

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this?
http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Here's the relevant JavaScript:

```
$(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        columnWidth: 100
      });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });
```